# Higher resolution when switching to tty terminal

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, tty

My laptop resolution is 1280x800 pixels. When I use switch to `tty` pressing ctrl+alt+F2..F5 the resolution comes down to 640x480 (or definitely something much lower than my laptop's native resolution.

My laptop has nvidiga geforce 9300 and I have installed official nvidia driver and it works fine for 3D games and stuff.

I have tried the guide [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ChangeTTYResolution) but it didn't affected anything!

Is there a way to fix this (in some config files or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this Ubuntu help entry:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ChangeTTYResolution

Comment: I did this before but it didnt change anything. maybe I because I have installed nvidia drivers?

Comment: Wait! I forgot to do update-grub...

Answer (score 0):

If vbeinfo in grub console or hwinfo --framebuffer (you need to install it:  `sudo apt-get install hwinfo` ) doesn't show the right resolution for your monitor, then follow [this](http://blog.samat.org/2010/11/09/High-resolution-text-console-with-uvesafb-and-Debian/) tutorial.
It is for debian, but it also works on ubuntu.